# question regarding substitution

Tags: integration

So I am taking a calculus II online course and we are working on u substitution techniques and I came across an unusual substitution:

$\int_{}^{} (\frac{x-4}{x^2+5})dx = \int_{}^{} (\frac{x}{x^2+5})dx -\int_{}^{} (\frac{4}{x^2+5})dx$

I split the integral into two and the first integral was simple and straightforward but the second one I'm struggling to understand how the book gets to their answer.

from "$\frac{1}{2}(\ln(x^2+5) -4\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{x^2+5}$"

$\frac{1}{2}(\ln(x^2+5)-\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}\arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}) +c$

specifically the $-\frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}\arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}) +c$

My working: $-4\int_{}^{}\frac{1}{x^2+5}dx$ =

$4\int_{}^{} \sqrt{\frac{1}{5(\frac{x^2}{5}+1)}}dx$ I infered from the steps that in order to get a substitution which will integrate and result in a tan inverse that they factored out a five in the denominator and took the the square root of the whole integrand.

$\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\int_{}^{} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{5}+1}}$ simplifying, I believe I believe the idea is to do a u substitution of:

$u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}$ to end up with arctan $\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}$ but I don't know how this would simplify to use $u=\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}$

and in the book, does the answer rationalize the denominator? My professor's seldom did that; so I'm a bit stuck.

Any help with some of these in between steps would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It helps a lot if you could remember that standard formula for the integration: $$\int\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x^2+a^2}$$ Look at @Bernard's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\int\frac{x-4}{x^2+5}=\int\frac{x}{x^2+5}-4\int\frac{1}{x^2+5}$

So the first one is pretty obvious, just $\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+5)+c$ (note that $x^2+5$ is positive so no need for absolute value.

We know that $\frac{d}{dx}\arctan(f(x))=\frac{1}{1+f^2(x)}\cdot\frac{d}{dx}f(x)$.

Now take $x=\sqrt{5}u\implies\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}\left(u^2+1\right)}du=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\arctan(u)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}\arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}})$.

Finally we conclunde $\int\frac{x-4}{x^2+5}=\frac{1}{2}\ln(x^2+5)-\frac{4}{\sqrt{5}}\arctan(\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}})+c$

Comment: Thankyou! That helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, any well-bred young people should know the general formula:
$$ \int\frac{\mathrm dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac 1a\,\arctan\frac xa.$$

Answer (score 0):

Let 
$$
g(x) = \frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}\, \arctan\left({\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}}\right)
$$
Using standard differentation,
\begin{align}
\frac{dg}{dx} &= \frac{4\sqrt{5}}{5}\, \frac{1}{({\frac{x}{\sqrt{5}}})^2 + 1} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} \\
&= \frac{4}{5}  \frac{5}{x^2 + 5} \\
&= \frac{4}{x^2 + 5}
\end{align}
So $g(x)$ has to be an antiderivative of the function
$$
\frac{4}{x^2 + 5}
$$